# How to join three lists into a single Object

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

How to transform three lists based on userId in a single object, where each object has the respected list object as a variable.

```kotlin
data class User(val id: String)
data class Book(val id: String, val userId: String)
data class Order(val id: String, val userId: String)
```

Input

```kotlin
val users: List<User> = listOf(
    User(id = "u1"),
    User(id = "u2"),
    User(id = "u3")
)
val books: List<Book> = listOf(
    Book(id = "b1.u1", userId = "u1"),
    Book(id = "b2.u1", userId = "u1"),
    Book(id = "b3.u2", userId = "u2"),
    Book(id = "b4.ux", userId = "ux")
)

val order: List<Order> = listOf(
    Order(id = "o1", userId = "u1"),
    Order(id = "o2", userId = "u1"),
    Order(id = "03", userId = "u2"),
    Order(id = "o4", userId = "u1")
)
```

Output

```kotlin
val result = listOf(Result(user, book, order))
```

Comment: What is your expected full output? Do you want all combinations of books and orders? Seems like there's no link between an order and a book.

Answer (score 2):

You can group the books and orders by userId and then for each user you can pick the corresponding books and orders.

```kotlin
val booksMap = books.groupBy { it.userId }
val ordersMap = orders.groupBy { it.userId }
users.map {
    Result(
        user = it,
        books = booksMap[it.id] ?: emptyList(),
        orders = ordersMap[it.id] ?: emptyList()
    )
}
```

Here `Result` is:

```kotlin
data class Result(val user: User, val books: List<Book>, val orders: List<Order>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to get exactly what you need as output. To me, it makes the most sense to get a list of books and orders for each user. If that is the case, then you can do this:

```
data class Result(val user: User, val books: List<Book>, val orders: List<Order>)

val results = users.map { user ->
    val userBooks = books.filter { it.userId == user.id }
    val userOrders = orders.filter { it.userId == user.id }
    Result(user, userBooks, userOrders)
}
```

Comment: Yes something similar, but is there a way, to avoid filter or chain each of them, kind of group by or associate by